# How to generate files using dart source_gen to a different directory

Tags: build, dart, code-generation

This issue describes the concept
https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/issues/272

To summarize:

- I am using source_gen to generate some dart code.
- I am using json_serializable on the generated dart code.
- I wish to output all of the results to a source directory adjacent or below my target source.

The desired directory structure

- src

  - feature_a

    - model.dart
    - gen

      - model.g.dart
      - model.g.g.dart
  - feature_b

    - ...

I have considered building to cache however it seems json_serializable doesn't support this and even if it did I don't know if its even possible to run a builder on files in the cache.

I've also considered an aggregated builder that is mentioned here.

[Generate one file for a list of parsed files using source_gen in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902443/generate-one-file-for-a-list-of-parsed-files-using-source-gen-in-dart)

But json_serializable is still an issue and the source_gen version in that post is super old and doesn't describe the solution well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with `build_runner`. The issue to follow is https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1689

Note that this doesn't help much with builders that you don't author, and wouldn't work with things like `SharedPartBuilder`.

Comment: Newer release now addres this I believe. Updates in the github link referenced in this post.